# Using OFFSET operator on an array in x86 Assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, offset

I'm currently going through *Assembly Language for x86 Processors 6th Edition* by Kip R. Irvine. It's quite enjoyable, but something is confusing me.

Early in the book, the following code is shown:

```
list BYTE 10,20,30,40
ListSize = ($ - list)
```

This made sense to me. Right after declaring an array, subtract the current location in memory with the starting location of the array to get the number of bytes used by the array.

However, the book later does:

```
.data
arrayB BYTE 10h,20h,30h 
.code
mov esi, OFFSET arrayB
mov al,[esi]
inc esi
mov al,[esi]
inc esi
mov al,[esi]
```

To my understanding, `OFFSET` returns the location of the variable with respect to the program's segment. That address is stored in the `esi` register. Immediates are then used to access the value stored at the address represented in `esi`. Incrementing moves the address to the next `byte`.

So what is the difference between using `OFFSET` on an array and simply calling the array variable? I was previously lead to believe that simply calling the array variable would also give me its address.

Comment: Depending on your assembler's syntax, using the array name will load the first element from memory, not the address.

Answer (score 1):

```
.data
Number dd 3
.code
mov eax,Number
mov ebx,offset Number
```

`EAX` will read memory at a certain address and store the number 3

`EBX` will store that certain address.

```
mov ebx,offset Number
```

is equivalent in this case to

```
lea ebx,Number
```

Comment: Again, this is assembler specific.  OP should really refer to his assembler documentation.  Most that I use, for example, will move the address into EAX in your first example.  Moving the content would require brackets or braces.